# Compare Map<String,Object> and print the diff attribute value

Tags: java

I want to compare  Request object and DB object in jersey PUT/PATCH request, so that requested object i have converted in *Map{String,Object}* reqObject, and DB object also i converted in *Map{String,Object}* db object.
Now I want to compare both map and print the diff value in log.
Please help me how to do in generic way.

```
if(!properties1.equals(properties2)){ 
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> empNew:properties1.entrySet()){ 
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> empOld:properties2.entrySet()){ 
            if((empNew.getKey().equals(empOld.getKey())&& !(empNew.getValue().equals(empOld.getValue())))){
                System.out.println("Update "+" "+empNew.getKey()+" "+"value"+" "+"from"+" "+empOld.getValue()+" "+"to"+" "+empNew.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My object Structure is like this:

```
{"id" : "5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3", 
 "name" : "Abed", 
 "address" : [{ "number" : "xyz", 
                "street" : "asdfgh", 
                "town" : "AMB6 Ind2", 
                "postcode" : "600039" } 
             ] 
}
```

Comment: OK. What have you tried?

Comment: Is it for testing purposes? If so, try `shazamcrest` and its `sameBeanAs` hamcrest matcher. https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest

Comment: if(!properties1.equals(properties2)){
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> empNew:properties1.entrySet()){  
 for(Map.Entry<String, Object> empOld:properties2.entrySet()){
if((empNew.getKey().equals(empOld.getKey())&& !(empNew.getValue().equals(empOld.getValue())))){
System.out.println("Update "+" "+empNew.getKey()+" "+"value"+" "+"from"+" "+empOld.getValue()+" "+"to"+" "+empNew.getValue());

Comment: My object Structure like this :::::: {
  "id" : "5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3",
  "name" : "Abed",
  "address" : [ {
    "number" : "xyz",
    "street" : "asdfgh",
    "town" : "AMB6 Ind2",
    "postcode" : "600039"
  } ]
}

Comment: i am getting address as key and value i am getting as array but i want to compare value level and check the attribute values and print. is this any API? if not then how to solve it ASAP please.

Comment: No this for developement @ Jaroslaw Pawlak